# Jmeter: Distributed testing

Tags: jmeter, master-slave, distributed-testing

a very common scenario which we all face.

1. I have a Master and 2 slaves.
2. A CSV data set with 20 unique users.
3. I want to run 10 users on each slave simultaneously.
4. Should I split 20 users in to 2 files of 10 each and upload the CSV in each of the Slaves? Or
5. 20 in each slaves and the thread count as 20?

I want to run for all the users but not twice.

As always has been Looking forward for thoughts?

Best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario is not common and it doesn't make a lot of sense either.

Whatever.

All JMeter slaves are executing the same test plan and know nothing about each other so:

4. "split 20 users in to 2 files of 10 each and upload the CSV in each of the Slaves"
5. set the number of threads in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to `10`, in case of 2 slaves you will have 20 virtual users in total

More information:

- [Apache JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)